# Why doesn't dist-upgrade give me kernel 4.4?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I'm running 14.04.05 (or at least that's what is says when I ssh in).
I periodically run
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
I see that my kernel updates quite often but it stays 3.13.something
and i also see or think i should have kernel 4.4.something
https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Why am I "stuck" on kernel 3.13?

Don't i want 4.4?

I hadn't paid any attention to the particular kernel version before but upon wondering about specter/meltdown I see i am not patched.
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-tell-if-your-linux-machine-is-patched-against-meltdown-and-spectre/

Answer (score 2):

The trusty kernel series 3.13 is supported until the end of life of 14.04 LTS, so you need *not* upgrade it.

You *can* upgrade it according to the following link, but it is **risky**. So you had better **backup** your system before doing it.

[wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

The support and end of life is described at the following link (scroll down ...),

[www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)